# Setting a LI to 100% height in a responsive framework

Tags: height, responsive-design, css

I divided my demo page into 10 list items that each use 10% width and 400px height. However I want each list item to be displayed with a 100% height that cover the entire screen. I'm trying to set the height of the list items, but when I use 'height:100%', the list items keep on disapearing. How can I manage this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
            <ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><div><h3>Felis catus</h3></div></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#03F;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
}

.cbp-rfgrid {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10%; /* Fallback */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 10);
    width: calc(100% / 10);
    height:400px; /* CURRENT HEIGHT, SHOULD BE 100% BROWSER HEIGHT  */
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(71,163,218,0.5);
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a:hover div {
    opacity: 1;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a div h3 {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to see where your problem is without live examples. Please provide at least a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) exposing your problem.

Comment: Hi Slytael, please check the solution below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `cbp-rfgrid` add `height:100%;` and change `height:400px;` to `height:100%;`

```
.cbp-rfgrid {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.cbp-rfgrid li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10%; /* Fallback */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% / 10);
    width: calc(100% / 10);
    height:100%; /* CURRENT HEIGHT, SHOULD BE 100% BROWSER HEIGHT  */
}
```

live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/g9nDQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

That issue is only because the `ul` containing the `li` have no height set. So the `li` take 100% of a `ul` who expand depending on his content.

Set a `height` to the ul and your `li` will have a `height based on the`ul` height.

But if you have multiple `li` with `height:100%`, a scrollbar will appear on the `ul` cause text after the `ul` tag will be right after the first `li` and over the second `li` (like that : http://jsfiddle.net/D5EHN/). A good way to counter that (setting the scrollbar on `body` instead of `ul`) is to calculate the number of `li` and make the simple calcul of number of li * 100% and then set the `li` height to 100% / number of li. So if you have 4 `li`, `ul` height will be 400% and li height will be 25% (Like that : http://jsfiddle.net/D5EHN/2/).

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

The 100% height is just equal to height:auto which only expand the height by its content. Try to set the height like min-height:400px something like that.